'ModuleNotFoundError' when trying to import all functions from one file to another in the same directory from installed python package
Running python 3.12 in VS Code.
I am working on a package to post on PyPi to share with a few coworkers and up my own abilities and I am in the middle of testing installation using a test build. I can install the package, but when importing the package I get a module not found error. My file structure for the package looks like so:
packageName
---__init__.py
---functionFiles
------__init__.py
------functionFile1.py
------functionFile2.py

My __init__.py file  under packageName looks like so:
from packageName.functionFiles import functionFile1
from packageName.functionFiles import functionFile2

My __init__.py file  under functionFiles looks like so:
from .functionFile1 import *
from .functionFile2 import *

functionFile2 has a group of import statements that look like this:
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import functionFile1 as ac

Every time I try to import the package in VS Code with import packageName as pn I get the following error as it tries to import everything in functionFile2:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named `functionFile1

I checked my system path, and the package is installed. I have confirmed the spelling is correct, but am unsure what could be wrong. I am running this in a separate file in a working directory. I do install to my global environment, but this is because there's no point where I wont need these functions.
What am I missing? I have tried everything and the package runs fine as just a regular repo. Like I can pull it down off git and everything checks out, I can test it using pytest or do live testing and it works great, so I am not sure what is going on. Please help, I am very badly stumped.

Where is the module not found error is raised ?
functionFile1 = fileFunction1 ? did you forgot a "." in front ?

@SamiTahri oh man apologizes, my dyslexia kicked in when I typed that. I fixed it. It was supposed to be functionFile1
